# Amongst 16 players playing a knockout tournament find probability only $P_1$ reaches the final given that both $P_1$ and $P_2$ both reach semifinal

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, conditional-probability

$16$ players $P_1,P_2,...,P_{16}$ play in a knockout tournament. Assuming that players are paired at random in each round. If all players are of equal strength then find the probability that $P_1$ reaches the final under the condition that $P_2$ reaches the semi final but not in final.

**My Attempt**
$P_1$ and $P_2$ both reach the semifinal so they are two among four persons who reached semi-final whose probability is $$\frac{\binom{14}{2}}{\binom{16}{4}}$$. Now in finals $P_1$ must be there but $P_2$ should not reach finals so $P_1$ is among the two persons reaching the final and there is another player(other than $P_2$) who reaches the final whose probability is $$\frac{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{4}{2}}$$.

So the required probability =$$\frac{\binom{14}{2}}{\binom{16}{4}}\times \frac{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{4}{2}}=\frac{1}{60}$$

Is my answer correct

Comment: I want to make sure  I understand the question you are asking. The probability you want is the probability of $P_1$ winning and $P_2$ reaching the semi-finals. I am thinking that means that there are four players that reach the semi-finals.

Comment: The title question asks for the probability that $P_1$ reaches the final and $P_2$ reaches the semifinal but not the final. The question in your post asks for the probability that $P_1$ reaches the final _given that_ $P_2$ reaches the semifinal but not the final. They are two different questions, with very different answers.

Comment: If it was my post, I would show more detail on the calculations. It is possible that you made an arithmetic error.

Comment: @TonyK I have edited the title

Comment: Now your answer seems way off to me. Given that you reach the semi-finals (and only that given) the probability that you win is $1/4$. Your number, to a slightly different problem is $1/60$. Therefore your answer does not seem right to me. Maybe I do not understand the question and/or the question is not properly phrased.

Comment: The questions are still different, because the given conditions are different. In the title, we are given "both $P_1$ and $P_2$ reach the semifinal". In the post, we are given only that $P_2$ reaches the semifinal but not the final. These are two completely differentconditions, and the two questions will have completely different answers.

Comment: If you write "given that both $P_1$ and $P_2$ both reach semifinal" the number of person before the semifinal should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE QUESTION IN THE OP'S QUESTION STATEMENT

(NOT THE QUESTION IN THE TITLE - for which the answer is obviously $\frac{1}{3}$)

Assume that $P_2$ is a losing semi-finalist. Then there are 15 people who are equally likely to be finalists.

The conditional probability that $P_1$ is a finalist is therefore $\frac{2}{15}$.

NOTE

It is irrelevant what $P_2$ does providing they are not a finalist.

Comment: You mean $\frac{\binom{14}{1}}{\binom{15}{2}}$

Comment: They have the same chance as being the winner or being the losing finalist as any other of 15 people. So I saw it as 2/15 directly.

Comment: @user1172706: I do not understand your calculation. wherever $P_1$ is placed, she has to win $3$ matches in order to become a finalist, and since each are of equal ability, she has a $Pr = \frac12\frac12\frac12$ of being a finalist. $P_1$ is a *particular* person, and must win her particular matches. Also, as $P_2$ is a losing semifinalist, she can't be placed in the same quarter as $P_1$.

Comment: @true blue anil   I am not considering winning or losing I am considering $P_1$ as being one of 15 people who have equal chances of success or failure.

Comment: @true blue anil . Once we know that $P_2$ is out of the running, $P_1$ has probability 1/15 of being the winner and 1/15 of being the losing finalist.

Comment: You are not taking into account that $P_1$ and $P_2$ **must not meet** before the semifinals.

Comment: @true blue anil. $P_1$ is no different from any other player in this regard. Given that $P_2 $ does not reach the final, the chance that someone wins the tournament is $1$. There are 15 possibilities for this person therefore the probability it is $P_1$ is precisely 1/15. Similarly for the losing finalist.

Comment: @trueblueanil  Consider: Playing the game lines the players up in a row, where places 1 and 2 are "reached the finals" and 1,2,3, and 4 are "reached the semi-finals", and so forth.  As the players are of equal strength, so that these assignments of players to places are *unbiased*.  So, we merely seek the probability that $P_1\in\{1,2\}$ given that $P_2\in\{3,4\}$.  That is: the probability for $P_1$ being in **two among the fifteen** places where $P_2$ is not placed.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: I am a bit confused. If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are placed in {$1,2$} and {$3,4$} they can't both reach the SF. I have corrected my answer using$15$ spaces left.

Comment: Title and actual question are not the same.

Comment: Symmetry : $2$ players are in final, $15$ are candidates ($16$ players minus Player P2). All $15$ remaining players have same probability to be finalist, so probability is $\frac{2}{15}$ for each of them.  If we had no information about player P2, the probability would be $\frac{2}{16}$, results are consistent.  The title says 'given that P1 is in semi-final', I dont take this information, I work with the question in the text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer the question in the title.

If we assume that $P_1$ and $P_2$ both reach the semifinals, then since each player is equally likely to win any match and each player is equally likely to face any other surviving player in the semifinals, by symmetry each pair of semifinalists is equally likely to reach the finals.

There are $6$ possible pairs of semifinalists.  Of those, $2$ include $P_1$ but don't include $P_2$.  Therefore, given that both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are semifinalists, the probability that $P_1$ reaches the finals but $P_2$ does not is $\frac 13$.

Answer (score 0):

- We want the  probability that $P_1$ reaches the finals and $P_2$ loses in the semi-finals
- The crux of the matter is that since players are of equal ability, each has a $Pr$ of $\frac12$ of winning or losing agalnst any opponent in any match, *it is only their position in the table that can produce the  outcome we desire*
- Without loss of generality, we  place $P_1$ at the top of the table (i.e. $1$)
- $P_2$ then has to be in position $5$ downwards ($12$ among $15$ left), with  $Pr=\frac{12}{15} = \frac 45$
- Whether a person loses or wins the semi-finals, her probability is simply $\frac12\frac12\frac12 = \frac18$, and so this applies to both $P_1$ and $P_2$
- Putting the pieces together, final ans $= \frac45\frac18\frac18 = \frac1{80}$

### Note:

AS there is a confusion about what the question is asking, I have tajen the interpretation that both $P_1$ and $P_2$ reach the semifinal and $P_1$ reaches the final.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote (cit.) "*given that both P1 and P2... reach semifinal*", which implies we have four semifinalists, with $P_1$ and $P_2$ among them.

There is a $(\frac{2}{3})$ chance that $P_1$ and $P_2$ do not meet in the semi, times $(\frac{1}{2})^2$ that $P_1$ advances, but not $P_2$,
and there is a $(\frac{1}{3})$ chance that $P_1$ and $P_2$ do meet in the semi, times $(\frac{1}{2})$ that $P_1$ advances, but not $P_2$.



This gives $$p = \frac{2}{12}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$$

---

You could however have meant the *overall* probability of the desired outcome that $P_1$ makes the final and $P_2$ loses his semi, evaluated before the tournament starts.

There is a $(\frac{14}{15})$ chance that $P_1$ and $P_2$ do not meet in R16, times $(\frac{1}{2})^2$ that both advance.
Then, there is a $(\frac{6}{7})$ chance that $P_1$ and $P_2$ do not meet in R8, times $(\frac{1}{2})^2$ that both advance.

So far, we have $p_{SF}=\frac{14\times 6}{16\times 15\times 7}$.

From here, there is a $(\frac{2}{3})$
chance that $P_1$ and $P_2$ do not meet in the semi, times $(\frac{1}{2})^2$ that $P_1$ advances, but not $P_2$,
and there is a $(\frac{1}{3})$ chance that $P_1$ and $P_2$ do meet in the semi, times $(\frac{1}{2})$ that $P_1$ advances, but not $P_2$.

This gives $$p=\frac{14\times 6\times 2}{16 \times 15\times 7 \times 6}=\frac{168}{10080}= 0.01\bar6$$.